# Spring data jpa or the custome dao implementation

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I need to migrate an old project into new platform. there were some other project that have been already migrated to spring boot project. But its been done by some extra talented member who is not in my organization now.

I would like to know the advantages and disadvantages of using the following code for data access layer over the latest Spring-data-jpa/Hibernate (I am good with boot + data).

from my personal understanding eachtime it calls a dao its going with a new hibernate session and that session will be committed as soon as the work done by that dao. If a user session request utilizes two dao classes how the transaction management is happening in this case. I see that this code is overiding the context with this new config.

Ultimate expectation from this question is weather to follow this code or spring data ?and what are the advantages

```
        package com.xxxx

    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
    import io.searchbox.client.JestClientFactory;
    import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
    import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient;
    import org.elasticsearch.search.builder.SearchSourceBuilder;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlPropertiesFactoryBean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
    import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
    import org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;
    import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
    import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

    import javax.sql.DataSource;
    import java.util.Locale;
    import java.util.Properties;

    @Configuration
    @SuppressWarnings("PMD.UseSingleton")
    @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = Application.class,
            excludeFilters = @Filter({Controller.class, Configuration.class}))
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    public class ApplicationContextConfig {

        @Autowired
        private ConnectorConfiguration connectorConfiguration;

        @Autowired
        private WebNotifyConnectorConfiguration webNotifyConnectorConfiguration;

        @Bean(name = "webNotifyDataSource")
        public DataSource getWebNotifyDataSource() {
            return getBasicDataSource(webNotifyConnectorConfiguration);
        }

        @Autowired
        @Bean(name = "webNotifySessionFactory")
        public SessionFactory getWebNotifySessionFactory(DataSource webNotifyDataSource) {
            LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(webNotifyDataSource);
            sessionBuilder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
            sessionBuilder.addAnnotatedClasses(PartnerNotify.class);
            return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
        }

        @Autowired
        @Bean(name = "webNotifyTransactionManager")
        public HibernateTransactionManager getWebNotifyTransactionManager(SessionFactory webNotifySessionFactory) {
            return new HibernateTransactionManager(webNotifySessionFactory);
        }

        private BasicDataSource getBasicDataSource(IConnectorConfiguration connectorConfiguration) {
            final BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName(connectorConfiguration.getDriverClassName());
            dataSource.setUrl(connectorConfiguration.getConnectionUrl());
            dataSource.setUsername(connectorConfiguration.getConnectionUsername());
            dataSource.setPassword(connectorConfiguration.getConnectionPassword());
            return dataSource;
        }

        private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
            properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect");
            return properties;
        }

        @Autowired
        @Bean(name = "partnerNotifyDao")
        public PartnerNotifyDao getPartnerNotifyDao(SessionFactory webNotifySessionFactory) {
            return new PartnerNotifyDaoImpl(webNotifySessionFactory);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your example.

It just that before Spring Boot we had to define all those beans manually whether we used Java @Configuration or the old xml-based config.

> If a user session request utilizes two dao classes how the transaction
>   management is happening in this case.

Well, it depends on how the transactions have been configured. More concretely, where are those @Transactional annotatioins and how the propagation has been set on those.

The first benefit of using Spring Boot + Spring Data JPA is that you don't have to write configurations like these. Instead, you just @EnableAutoConfiguration, @EnableJpaRepositories and put some config in application.yml and you get DataSouce, Hibernate SessionFactory, etc instanciated by the Boot for you.

ApplicationContextConfig:

```
@Configuration
@SuppressWarnings("PMD.UseSingleton")
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = Application.class,
        excludeFilters = @Filter({Controller.class, Configuration.class}))
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {PartnerNotifyDao.class})
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = User.class)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationContextConfig {

}
```

application.yml:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: <your driver>
    url: <jdbc url>
    username: <db username>
    password: <db password>
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
    database: oracle
    show-sql: true
```

If your app is simple, using only one data source, one tx manager I suggest using Spring Boot simplified configuration.